# How do I cleanly determine if a file is not of the type I want?

Tags: java, file, kryo

I am using Kryo to save binary files of user data. The user can open one of their files in my application. I'm not sure if I have a clean approach to detecting whether they tried to open a file of some other type.

Right now, I'm writing a simple FileHeader object to the file before the user's data. The file header has info about what version of the app saved the file.

```
public void write (UserProject project, File file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    OutputStream outputStream = new DeflaterOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
    Output output = new Output(outputStream);
    kryo.writeObject(output, new FileHeader());
    kryo.writeObject(output, project);
    output.close();
}
```

So when I load a file, I can try to deserialize the file header and the user project and catch any Exception that might occur. But doing a catch-all block could hide certain issues I could perhaps react to in a more elegant way that simply showing the user an error no matter the exception. Here's what I'm doing now:

```
public Project read (File file) throws FileNotFoundException, FileVersionException, UnreadableException {
    InputStream inputStream = new InflaterInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    Input input = new Input(inputStream);

    try {
        FileHeader fileHeader = kryo.readObject(input, FileHeader.class);

        if (fileHeader.fileVersion > CURRENT_FILE_VERSION)
            throw new FileVersionException(/* */);

        Project project = kryo.readObject(input, Project.class);
        return project;
    } catch (Exception e){
        if (DEBUG) e.printStackTrace();
        throw new UnreadableException(e); //caller will show user error msg
    } finally {
        input.close();
    }
}
```

I suppose there's also a very tiny (infinitesimal?) chance that some file actually loads without throwing an exception, in which case a very unexpected error could happen elsewhere in my application. Not sure if I should worry about this...a user should not expect to open an incorrect file type and have it work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use magic numbers, a set of bytes that describes the type of file. Like .jpg, .pdf, .wav, etc. all have a few bytes at the beginning of each file, so even if these types are saved with different extensions you can check to see if the file's magic number is OK.

[Magic Number Description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29#Magic_numbers_in_files)

However, if you're serializing and deserializing you may have to tack on some additional data to the file after serializing and remove it before deserializing.